# WebSocketListener EOF Exception

Tags: android, websocket, okhttp, eofexception, wsapi

I'm trying to get response of an audio byte array from WebSocketApi by sending it through Okhttp3-(WebSocketListener).
But am getting EOFException in onFailure() of WebSocketListener while sending audio byte array.

My code:

//Establishing connection with WS api

```
        client = new OkHttpClient();            
        listener = new EchoWebSocketListener();
        request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://AUDIO_PROCESSING_URL").build();
        ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
        client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
```

// Sending audio byte array to WS api

```
 @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {            
        String bytes = ByteString.of(AudioData).toString();      
        webSocket.send(bytes);
    }
```

//ERROR

```
    : onFailure: java.io.EOFException
    : onFailure t.getMessage(): null
```

Please help me to find it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you immediately shutting down the client after creating it?

Comment: Because I am trying to send data only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to close the connection after sending the data instead of shutting down the client.

```
public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {            
    String bytes = ByteString.of(AudioData).toString();      
    webSocket.send(bytes);
    webSocket.close(1000, null); // close ws connection
}
```